# query ElasticSearch from JQuery (or Angular) : No Living connections

Tags: jquery, angular, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm starting with ES and at first time I just would like to make a simple test to ping my ES local instance, which is running, through JQuery or Angular.

I've made my own test using JQuery or I also followed this example : https://github.com/spalger/elasticsearch-angular-example

But I always get the same error : **No Living connections**.

I also tried through Java but there it works, I can query my ES local instance.

Thank you in advance for your ideas !

I'm using ES 2.4.6 but have the same issue with 5.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you didn't specify the schema on your host. Try adding `http://` to it.  It worked for me once I added that and used a server with CORS configured.

```
ExampleApp.service('client', function (esFactory) {
  return esFactory({
    host: 'http://localhost:9200',
    apiVersion: '2.3',
    log: 'trace'
  });
});
```

It could also be that your ES server requires authentication.  Can you browse to the ES server without credentials?

Comment: Indeed, everything works with the http prefix. I already tried before but CORS was not yet configured. So yes the two are required. Thank you !